# How to retrieve data from a 3rd table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

my question is, I got three tables, Files, Documents and Images, where a file can have many documents and a document can have many images.

So what I'm trying to do, is getting all the images from all the documents in one File. I tried something like this:

```
var exp = context.Files.Include(x => x.Documents.Select(s => s.Images)).ToList();
                var Doc = exp.Documents;
                foreach(var docs in Doc)
                {
                    listImg.Add(docs.Images);
                }
```

But it doesn't work, it says, cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' to 'Entities.Images'.

Any idea of how to fix this or doing it another way?

Comment: Can you show the class of this List `listImg`?\

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `SelectMany`:

```
var listImg = context.Files
                     .SelectMany(f => f.Documents)
                     .SelectMany(d => d.Images)
                     .ToList();
```

As for the exception: you defined `listImg` as `List<Entities.Images>` so you have to add `Images` objects to it, not `ICollection<Images>` objects. But, as you see, you don't need the `Add` method because you can create the list in one statement.

By the way, it's recommended to use singular names for classes, i.e. `Image` instead of `Images`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add directly the value to a list without declaring a class of a List itself.

**Your Code**

```
 foreach(var docs in Doc)
 {
      listImg.Add(docs.Images);
 }
```

**Change to** 
Assuming that you have already created a class  of this `listImg`

```
public class GetList
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public Image thisImage{get;set;}
}
```

**To Implement**

```
List<GetList> listImg = new List<GetList>();
foreach(var docs in Doc)
     {
         GetList gl = new GetList();
          gl.id = 1  // assuming an id to 1
          gl.thisImage = docs.Images //if this is a true image
          listImg.Add(gl);
     }
```